# Jmeter JSR223 Sampler - Unable to Write Data To CSV File

Tags: csv, jmeter, jsr223

I'm using Jmeter v **4.0 r1823414**. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820389/unable-to-set-incremental-variable-in-jmeter?noredirect=1#comment88652169_50822368), there is an advisory to use JSR223 PostProcessor, verbatim:

> it is recommended to use Groovy for any form of scripting to consider
>   migrating to JSR223 PostProcessor

Before this approach I tried to use BeanShell Sampler to simply write data to csv file. The code sample I took from the [blazemeter tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/saving-data-to-csv-files-with-java-through-jmeter) page. However, I was getting error

```
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.FileWriter; import java.util.Arrays; import java.io.Writer; impor . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name
```

Well, since it was suggested to move to **JSR223 Sampler** (or PostProcessor, not sure what's the difference between them in terms of functionality), I modified the code a little bit to be more Java based to be used in **JSR223 Sampler**:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    //Default separator
    private static char SEPARATOR = ',';

    //get path of csv file (creates new one if its not exists)
    private static String csvFile = "C:/TiredOfProgramming/Work/results.csv"; // for example '/User/Downloads/blabla.csv'

    private static String[] params = {"hello", "world", "jmeter"};

    //function write line in csv
    private static void writeLine(FileWriter writer, String[] parameters, char separator) throws IOException
    {
        boolean firstParameter = true;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String parameter = " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
        {
            //get param
            parameter = parameters[i];
            log.info(parameter);

            //if the first param in the line, separator is not needed
            if (!firstParameter)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(separator);
            }

            //Add param to line
            stringBuilder.append(parameter);

            firstParameter = false;
        }

        //prepare file to next line
        stringBuilder.append("\n");

        //add to file the line
        log.info(stringBuilder.toString());
        writer.append(stringBuilder.toString());
    }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);
        writeLine(fileWriter, params, SEPARATOR);

        //proper close to file
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
}
```

This particular script fails with the message:

> Script8.groovy: 15: unexpected token: hello @ line 15, column 39.
>          private static String[] params = {"hello", "world", "jmeter"};

If I test this in **IntelliJ IDE** with just wrapping writeLine method into the main method, everything works fine

```
package com.tiredofprogramming;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    //Default separator
    private static char SEPARATOR = ',';

    //get path of csv file (creates new one if its not exists)
    private static String csvFile = "C:\\TiredOfProgramming\\Work\\results.csv"; // for example '/User/Downloads/blabla.csv'

    private static String[] params = {"hello", "world", "jmeter"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);
        writeLine(fileWriter, params, SEPARATOR);
        //proper close to file
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    }


    //function write line in csv
    private static void writeLine(FileWriter writer, String[] parameters, char separator) throws IOException
    {
        boolean firstParameter = true;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String parameter = " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
        {
            //get param
            parameter = parameters[i];
            System.out.println(parameter);

            //if the first param in the line, separator is not needed
            if (!firstParameter)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(separator);
            }

            //Add param to line
            stringBuilder.append(parameter);

            firstParameter = false;
        }

        //prepare file to next line
        stringBuilder.append("\n");

        //add to file the line
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        writer.append(stringBuilder.toString());

  }
}
```

My question is: does groovy sampler understand Java (in one of SO post I saw mention that Groovy understands 99% of the java syntax). Was anyone ever successful at writing data into the csv file using Jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this slight modification:

```
//Default separator
char SEPARATOR = ',';

//get path of csv file (creates new one if its not exists)
String csvFile = "C:\\TiredOfProgramming\\Work\\results.csv"; // for example '/User/Downloads/blabla.csv'

def params = ["hello", "world", "jmeter"];

//function write line in csv
def writeLine(FileWriter writer, List<String> parameters, char separator) throws IOException {
    boolean firstParameter = true;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String parameter = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
        //get param
        parameter = parameters[i];
        log.info(parameter);

        //if the first param in the line, separator is not needed
        if (!firstParameter) {
            stringBuilder.append(separator);
        }

        //Add param to line
        stringBuilder.append(parameter);

        firstParameter = false;
    }

    //prepare file to next line
    stringBuilder.append("\n");

    //add to file the line
    log.info(stringBuilder.toString());
    writer.append(stringBuilder.toString());
}

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile, true);
writeLine(fileWriter, params, SEPARATOR);

//proper close to file
fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Create CSV]

However there are easier method to achieve the same in Groovy, check out:

- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Files](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-files.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T for quick response, it worked.I thought that Groovy accepts Java syntax, but you changed the code: removed import statements, methods are now defined with def keyword, array of params strings are enclosed with square brackets... I will let Blazemeter support team know that their script needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the code below. It is a simple code snippet but you can successfully write into csv file from Jmeter using JSR223 Postprocessor.

```java
//get the JSON response from prev sampler

import com.eclipsesource.json.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

    String getResponse = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

    //parse the response and convert to string
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_JSON_SIMPLE);
    String parResponse = parser.parse(getResponse);

    String preResponse = parResponse.toString();
    //replace all commas with a semi-colon
    String csvResponse = preResponse.replaceAll(",", ";");

    //log response to file
    logFileName = "C:/apache-jmeter-5.1.1/Web_Service_Output.csv";
    BufferedWriter outLog = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFileName, true));
    outLog.write(csvResponse + "\n");
    outLog.close();
```