# how to write in csv ${__threadNum}${__time(ddMMyyyy,)}${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration();,)} in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am generating some unique number by combination of  ${__threadNum}${__time(ddMMyyyy,)}${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration();,)}
now i want to write same number in csv or txt in jmeter.
I am using bean shell post processor for this.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. [You should not be inlining JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

Assuming above points here is the relevant Groovy piece of code

```
def first = ctx.getThreadNum()
def second = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('ddMMyyyy').format(new Date())
def third = vars.getIteration()

new File('myFile.txt') << first << second << third
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:-

```
int random_var = ${__threadNum}${__time(ddMMyyyy,)}${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration();,)};
f = new FileOutputStream("D:/Output1.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(random_var);
f.flush();
f.close();
```

[image]

There are various ways but above is one example.For performance improvement it is recommended to use groovy.
Other help articles:-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/saving-data-to-csv-files-with-java-through-jmeter
For groovy check:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597623/jmeter-jsr223-sampler-unable-to-write-data-to-csv-file